# firebase_functions/internal Response is not valid JSON object cloud functions when region is specified why?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I tried to specify `asia-south1` for my **https on call** function when a event is triggred i'm getting error `[firebase_functions/internal] Response is not valid JSON object cloud functions` in my debug console. In firebase cloud function log .Function is not at all getting triggred.

**Code snippet**

```
//index.js

exports.disableUserAccount = functions.region("asia-south1").https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  try {
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    if (uid.length !== 0) {
      console.log("User uid : " + uid);
      await admin.auth().updateUser(context.auth.uid, {
        disabled: true,
      });
      console.log("User account disabled successfully");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error :" + error.toString());
  }
});
```

**Flutter snippet**

```
import 'package:cloud_functions/cloud_functions.dart';

Future<void> callUserDisableFunction() async{
    try{
    FirebaseFunctions disableFunction = FirebaseFunctions.instance;
    var callFunction = disableFunction.httpsCallable("disableUserAccount");
    await callFunction();
    print("disableUserAccount function is triggered");
    } catch (error){
      print("Error in https callable : ${error.toString()}");
    }
  }
```

**Note :** deploying with default region `us-central1`works fine.
Why can't i specify region in https on call ? And how is it working with `us-central1` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by [the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions)

> Firebase Hosting supports Cloud Functions in us-central1 only.

As you may probably know Firebase Functions is a GCP Function behind however Firebase Hosting only supports us-central1, you could look at alternaitves like [cloud run](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/cloud-run) since this is supported by Firebase hosting.